# Selecting rows from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` like the following:

```
   var1 var2 var3
    0    20   0
    0    0    0 
    10   0   10
    0    0    0
    ...
```

Let say I want to return indices where the value will meet the certain constraints: say any value that is above the mean value of that column: so in above example, it shall return 
row 1, 2, 3, but not 4.

I tried:

```
 which( df > mean(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

However, this will return a flattened array index (3, 5 ...).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use arr.ind=TRUE for array index

```
    df<-c(1,2,3,4,3,4,3,5,6,4)
    which(df>mean(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: this will return indices of flattened array, not row index of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly:

```
idx <- (1:nrow(df))[apply(df, 1, function(row) any(row > mean(df)))]
```

This will give you the numeric row indices for which some value in each row is above the mean value in the `data.frame`.